# Creating New Age group

Tags: r, dataframe, paste, cut

I have some age(12:54) and related data for them (here year and ASFR). The year starts from 1933 to 1987.
The structure of the data is something like ensuing:

| year | age | Asfr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1933 | 12 | .00004 |
| 1933 | 13 | .00044 |
| 1933 | 14 | .00177 |
| 1933 | 15 | .00672 |
| 1933 | 16 | .01875 |
| 1933 | 17 | .03846 |
| 1933 | 18 | .06586 |
| 1933 | 19 | .08719 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1933 | 49 | .00037 |
| 1933 | 50 | .00009 |
| 1933 | 51 | .00003 |
| 1933 | 52 | .00003 |
| 1933 | 53 | .00003 |
| 1933 | 54 | .00002 |

Now, I need codes by which I can turn this data into age groups with the following structure:

"15-19" , "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39" ,"40-44", "45-49"

in which I want 15-19 age group be the sum of 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19

20-24 age group be the sum of 20, 21, 22, 23, 24

Finally, the last age group be the sum of 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,54

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Don't you think it's curious: *15-19 age group be the sum of 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19*. Why 12,13,14? or Why not 12-19?

Comment: Because the data consist of ages from 12 to 55; however, most software and analysis are based on age groups consisting from 15 to 49.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(age_group = case_when(age %in% c(12:19) ~ "15-19",
                               age %in% c(20:24) ~ "20-24",
                               age %in% c(25:29) ~ "25-29",
                               age %in% c(30:34) ~ "30-34",
                               age %in% c(35:39) ~ "35-39",
                               age %in% c(40:44) ~ "40-44",
                               age %in% c(45:49) ~ "45-49",
                               age > 49 ~ "50+")) %>% 
  group_by(age_group, year) %>% 
  summarize(total_asfr = sum(Asfr),
            age_group_n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  age_group total_asfr age_group_n
  <chr>          <dbl>       <int>
1 15-19        0.0385            2
2 20-24        0.00044           1
3 30-34        0.00177           1
4 45-49        0.00672           1
5 50+          0.0188            1
```

Using sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1933L, 1933L, 1933L, 1933L, 1933L, 1933L
), age = c(12L, 23L, 34L, 45L, 56L, 17L), Asfr = c(4e-05, 0.00044, 
                                                   0.00177, 0.00672, 0.01875, 0.03846)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This code is useful. However, I need the sum of asfrs simultaneously.

Comment: @MohammadHaddadi I updated the answer - check it out.

Comment: You just need to change the `group_by` to `group_by(age_group, year)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
# Import tidyverse or dplyr
library(tidyverse)

#create the age groups and group by Year and age_groups    
df %>% mutate(age_groups = cut(df$age,
                           breaks=c(12, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45,55),
                           right= F) ) %>% 
  group_by(year, age_groups) %>% 
  summarise(asfr_total = sum(Asfr))
```

You should see something like this:

```
   year age_groups asfr_total
  <dbl> <fct>           <dbl>
1  1933 [12,20)          4.32
2  1933 [20,25)          2.33
3  1933 [25,30)          2.68
4  1933 [30,35)          2.89
5  1933 [35,40)          2.23
6  1933 [40,45)          2.85
7  1933 [45,55)          6.05
```

Comment: Thank you dear @gurezende